# STL push_back optimize cause array subscript is above array bounds

Tags: c++, stl, g++

Test environment:

- CentOS 7.0 g++ 4.8.2
- Arch Linux g++ 4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease)
- Arch Linux g++ 4.9.1

Compile command cases:

1. PASS: g++ -Wall t.cpp
2. FAIL: g++ -Wall -O2 t.cpp
3. PASS: g++ -Wall -O2 t.cpp # and replace 2 with 3 on line 13
4. PASS: g++ -Wall -O2 t.cpp # and comment out line 14
5. PASS: g++ -Wall -O2 --std=c++11 t.cpp # for g++ 4.8/4.9

The FAIL message:

```
t.cpp: In member function ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vecto
<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Object; _Alloc = std::allocator<Ob
ject>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Object*, s
td::vector<Object> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = Object*]’
t.cpp:17:15: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     ~Object() {};
               ^
t.cpp:17:15: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
```

t.cpp

```
#include <vector>                      
class TestCls {                        
public:                                
    TestCls() {};                      
    virtual ~TestCls() {};             
};                                     
class TestCls1 : public TestCls        
{                                      
};                                     
class Object {                         
public:                                
    TestCls    m_member[2];            
    TestCls1   m_member1[2]; // LINE 13, if change to [3] it works.
    TestCls1   m_member2[2]; // LINE 14, if comment out this line, it works.

    Object() {};                       
    ~Object() {}; // LINE 17 the warning line                     
};                                     
class Container {                      
public:                                
    std::vector<Object> m_obj;         

    Container() {};                    
    ~Container() {};                   
};                                     
int main() {                           
        Container con;                 
        Object obj;                    
        con.m_obj.push_back(obj);      
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bogus warning, there are a few similar ones on [Gcc Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=array%20subscript%20is%20above%20array%20bounds&list_id=95076). Passing `std=c++11` / `std=c++1y` makes the warning disappear, as does making `TextCls` non-virtual.

Comment: same behaviour in g++ 4.8.3 for me

Comment: @black, yes, it compiles with all versions, the point is it gives a bogus warning with `-O2 -Wall`

Comment: Also adding some member variable (say, `int`) in `TestCls` AND `TestCls1` makes the warning disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but I don't know the reason.

```
// ...
class Object {
public:
    // ...
    ~Object();
};
Object::~Object() {}; // move to outside LINE 19
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of bogus warning generated by GCC due to issues with Value Range Propagation (which is the middle-end pass that generates array bounds warnings) interacting with the various loop optimizer passes (such as loop peeling and loop unrolling).  As is mentioned in the various bugzillas [linked](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=array%20subscript%20is%20above%20array%20bounds&list_id=95076), these represent missed optimization opportunities as well, but the underlying issue (or issues) in VRP have proved elusive for the GCC developers.  That said, reporting this occurrence to the GCC Bugzilla is a good idea, especially since you have a MWE at hand.

Answer (score -1):

> gcc -Wall enables all compiler's warning messages. This option should
>   always be used, in order to generate better code.

So, try delete -Wall. Example:

- with -Wall http://goo.gl/d4cces
- without -Wall http://goo.gl/4vY2Un

Comment: I know I could disable it, but force warnings on for detect hidden errors.

Comment: @DanielYCLin delete "virtual" in "virtual ~TestCls() {};". See http://goo.gl/hjGwh5

Comment: The virtual is required for my program, this is just a simplified version.

Comment: I'd even suggest `-Wextra`.

Comment: This is a symptom of a deeper compiler issue (bug) -- simply stuffing a gag in the compiler's mouth over a single bogus warning is a bad idea.